# Jenkins not accessible due to "JVM is terminating. Shutting down Jetty" in ECS with no exceptions/errors

Tags: docker, jenkins, terraform, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I am trying to deploy a Jenkins instance in an AWS ECS using a docker image I pushed to ECR. All the infrastructure required for this deployment was built using Terraform.

So far, I managed to build and run a container based on the following Docker file in my local machine with no issues:

However, when it comes to deploy it to AWS ECS, I see that Jenkins initializes fine, however, when it is about to start, it ends with message: `JVM is terminating. Shutting down Jetty`

I set the logging level of Jenkins to FINEST to gather all possible causes for this behavior, but I do not see any error. These are the logs happening before Jenkins:

```
2021-05-20T11:29:33.725-05:00   FINE: adding implicit dependency zulip → sshd because of 1.653

2021-05-20T11:29:33.725-05:00   May 20, 2021 4:29:33 PM jenkins.model.Jenkins setInstallState

2021-05-20T11:29:33.725-05:00   FINE: Install state transitioning from: INITIAL_SECURITY_SETUP to : NEW

2021-05-20T11:29:33.725-05:00   May 20, 2021 4:29:33 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onTaskCompleted

2021-05-20T11:29:33.725-05:00   FINE: Completed Finalizing set up

2021-05-20T11:29:33.726-05:00   May 20, 2021 4:29:33 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained

2021-05-20T11:29:33.726-05:00   INFO: Completed initialization

2021-05-20T11:29:33.726-05:00   May 20, 2021 4:29:33 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained

2021-05-20T11:29:33.726-05:00   FINE: Attained Finalizing set up

2021-05-20T11:29:33.726-05:00   May 20, 2021 4:29:33 PM jenkins.model.Jenkins save

2021-05-20T11:29:33.726-05:00   FINE: setting version 1.0 to 2.293

2021-05-20T11:29:33.732-05:00   May 20, 2021 4:29:33 PM jenkins.util.SystemProperties getString

2021-05-20T11:29:33.732-05:00   CONFIG: Property (default): hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener.hostName => null

2021-05-20T11:29:33.733-05:00   May 20, 2021 4:29:33 PM jenkins.util.SystemProperties getString

2021-05-20T11:29:33.733-05:00   CONFIG: Property (default): hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener.port => null

2021-05-20T11:29:33.738-05:00   May 20, 2021 4:29:33 PM jenkins.branch.WorkspaceLocatorImpl load

2021-05-20T11:29:33.738-05:00   FINER: cache miss on /var/jenkins_home/workspace

2021-05-20T11:29:33.750-05:00   May 20, 2021 4:29:33 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run

2021-05-20T11:29:33.750-05:00   INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running

2021-05-20T11:29:33.771-05:00   May 20, 2021 4:29:33 PM jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller install

2021-05-20T11:29:33.771-05:00   FINE: Effective SlaveRestarter on : null

2021-05-20T11:29:34.030-05:00   May 20, 2021 4:29:34 PM jenkins.util.JSONSignatureValidator verifySignature

2021-05-20T11:29:35.652-05:00   May 20, 2021 4:29:35 PM hudson.model.DownloadService$Downloadable load

2021-05-20T11:29:35.652-05:00   INFO: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tools.JDKInstaller

2021-05-20T11:29:35.652-05:00   May 20, 2021 4:29:35 PM hudson.util.Retrier start

2021-05-20T11:29:35.652-05:00   INFO: Performed the action check updates server successfully at the attempt #1

2021-05-20T11:29:35.659-05:00   May 20, 2021 4:29:35 PM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork lambda$doRun$0

2021-05-20T11:29:35.659-05:00   INFO: Finished Download metadata. 38,688 ms

2021-05-20T11:29:58.009-05:00   May 20, 2021 4:29:58 PM winstone.Logger logInternal

2021-05-20T11:29:58.009-05:00   INFO: JVM is terminating. Shutting down Jetty
```

I do not see any warn/error in the previous logs (null stuff appears in my local as well, so I do not think there is an issue there).

This is the TF code I am using:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12"
  required_providers {
      aws = {
          version = "3.15"
          source = "hashicorp/aws"
      }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
    region  = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "jenkinsdev_loggroup" {
    name = "jenkinsdev-loggroup"
}

resource "aws_ecr_repository" "jenkinsdev_repo" {
    name    = "jenkinsdev-repo"
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "jenkinsdev_cluster" {
    name    = "jenkinsdev-cluster"
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "jenkinsdev_task" {
    family                  = "jenkinsdev-task"
    container_definitions   = <<DEFINITION
    [
        {
            "name": "jenkinsdev-task",
            "image": "${aws_ecr_repository.jenkinsdev_repo.repository_url}",
            "essential": true,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 8080,
                    "hostPort": 8080
                }
            ],
            "memory": 512,
            "cpu": 256,
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.jenkinsdev_loggroup.name}",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "jenkinsdev"
                }
            },
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "JENKINS_ADMIN_ID",
                    "value": "user01"
                },
                {
                    "name": "JENKINS_ADMIN_PASSWORD",
                    "value": "password01"
                },
                {
                    "name": "JAVA_OPTS",
                    "value": "-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/jenkins_home/log.properties"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    DEFINITION
    requires_compatibilities    = ["FARGATE"]
    network_mode                = "awsvpc"
    memory                      = 2048
    cpu                         = 1024
    execution_role_arn          = aws_iam_role.ecsTaskExecutionRole.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecsTaskExecutionRole" {
    name                = "ecsTaskExecutionRole"
    assume_role_policy  = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_policy.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role_policy" {
    statement {
      actions   = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
      principals {
        type    = "Service"
        identifiers = [ "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com" ]
      }
    }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecsTaskExecutionRole_policy" {
    role        = aws_iam_role.ecsTaskExecutionRole.name
    policy_arn  = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "jenkinsdev_service" {
    name            = "jenkinsdev-service"
    cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.jenkinsdev_cluster.id
    task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.jenkinsdev_task.arn
    launch_type     = "FARGATE"
    desired_count   = 1

    load_balancer {
      target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.target_group.arn
      container_name = aws_ecs_task_definition.jenkinsdev_task.family
      container_port = 8080
    }

    network_configuration {
      subnets       = ["subnet-111", "subnet-222", "subnet-333"]
      assign_public_ip = true
      security_groups = [aws_security_group.service_security_group.id]
    }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "load_balancer_security_group" {
    vpc_id          = "vpc-000"
    
    ingress {
      protocol      = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks   = [ "0.0.0.0/0" ]
      from_port     = 80
      to_port       = 80
    }

    egress {
      protocol = "-1"
      cidr_blocks = [ "0.0.0.0/0" ]
      from_port = 0
      to_port = 0
    }
}

# Adding Security Group for service
resource "aws_security_group" "service_security_group" {
    vpc_id          = "vpc-000"

    ingress {
      protocol          = "-1"
      from_port         = 0
      to_port           = 0
      security_groups   = [aws_security_group.load_balancer_security_group.id]
    }

    egress {
      protocol = "-1"
      cidr_blocks = [ "0.0.0.0/0" ]
      from_port = 0
      to_port = 0
    }
}

resource "aws_alb" "jenkinsdev_load_balancer" {
    name                = "jenkinsdev-lb-tf"
    load_balancer_type  = "application"
    subnets             = ["subnet-111", "subnet-222", "subnet-333"]
    security_groups     = [aws_security_group.load_balancer_security_group.id]
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "target_group" {
    name            = "target-group"
    port            = 8080
    protocol        = "HTTP"
    target_type     = "ip"
    vpc_id          = "vpc-000"
    
    health_check {
      matcher   = "200"
      path      = "/"
    }

    depends_on = [
      aws_alb.jenkinsdev_load_balancer
    ]
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener" {
    load_balancer_arn   = aws_alb.jenkinsdev_load_balancer.arn
    port                = 80
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    
    default_action {
      type  = "forward"
      target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.target_group.arn
    }
}
```

I do not think the Docker file would be really useful since it works well on local, but attaching anyway:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:latest
ENV JAVA_OPTS -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
ENV CASC_JENKINS_CONFIG /var/jenkins_home/casc.yaml
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
COPY log.properties /var/jenkins_home/log.properties
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
COPY casc.yaml /var/jenkins_home/casc.yaml
```

I've tried adding more memory in the task definition, however, seems like the issue is not there.

Thanks in advance for any help or clue.

Comment: hum, same here, but in different environment. Running a docker container in a vagrant image, running in my local laptop, using docker run command, using defaults. Do you have any clue about this?

Comment: Hey, have you solved this Issue?  having the same right now when deploying jenkins with Kubernetes.